# How to use Stream<E> instead of Collection<E> or List<E>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following class I have currently:

```
public interface Drawable {
    public void compileProgram();

    public Program getProgram();

    public int getDataSize();

    public FloatBuffer putData(final FloatBuffer dataBuffer);

    public int getDataMode();

    public static int countDataSize(final Collection<Drawable> drawables) {
        return drawables.stream().mapToInt((drawable) -> drawable.getDataSize()).sum();
    }

    public static FloatBuffer putAllData(final List<Drawable> drawables) {
        FloatBuffer dataBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(countDataSize(drawables) * 3);
        drawables.stream().forEachOrdered((drawable) -> dataBuffer.put(drawable.putData(dataBuffer)));
        return (FloatBuffer)dataBuffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Now take a look at `countDataSize`:

- I have as input `Collection<Drawable>`, because I do not care about the order, I just want to sum up their size.
- I use `drawables.stream()`, which would be redundant if I would've passed in a `Stream<Drawable>` argument.

And next take a look at `putAllData`:

- As in put here I have `List<Drawable> drawables`, as the order this time does matter.
- I use `drawables.stream()` to access them, this happens in order with `forEachOrdered()`.

I wush to use `Stream<Drawable>` as input, however does passing in a `Collection<Drawable>` or `List<Drawable>` even work then? If it does, how can I ensure that in the first case the order does not matter, while in the second case it does matter?

Comment: Side comment: `drawables.stream().mapToInt((drawable) -> drawable.getDataSize()).sum();` can be written `drawables.stream().mapToInt(Drawable::getDataSize).sum();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to use `Stream<Drawable>` as input, however does passing in a `Collection<Drawable>` or `List<Drawable>` even work then?

No, streams are not part of the Collection class hierarchy, so if your method expects a `Stream<e>` it can't accept a `Collection/List<E>`.

Also note that passing streams around does not necessarily add so much benefit in your case because streams can only be consumed once. For example this would not work:

```
Stream<E> s = ...;
putAllDate(s);
countDataSize(s); //IllegalStateException
```

The last statement would cause a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense indeed, had not considered that before. Any clue how it would translate in bytecode, because enormous performance penalty are not worth the streams in this case?

Comment: @skiwi I have not measured but the performance penalty is probably minimal - in the end it is going to iterate over your collection and add ints, more or less the same way you would write it as a loop.

Comment: @skiwi The big performance improvement will come with `countDataSize` if you have a lot (>10,000) elements: write `drawables.parallelStream().mapToInt(Drawable::getDataSize).sum();` to get parallel execution.